# Installing MySQL in ubuntu with putty

Tags: server, mysql, putty

So...i'm trying to install MySQL Server in Ubuntu 10.04 (i don't want other version of ubuntu) and it don't works...
I tried :

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

and also

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.1
```

and i get this :

[image]

I also tried :

```
sudo aptitude install mysql-server
```

and i get this :

[image]

Why do I get this??

Comment: It seems it cannot connect to the repository. Did you try running "sudo apt-get update"? Also, check your /etc/apt/sources.list file. Paste its contents in the question too.

Comment: Are you able to connect to internet? Are you behind a proxy? Kindly edit your question with more details.

Comment: 1.I'm connected to server with putty, so...i have internet connection...but i say before...it works with sudo apt-get update...Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running

```
sudo apt-get update
```

That should fix the problem.